# bad solution to the knapsack problem on Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, qubo

To solve the knapsack problem, I translate it into a QUBO. But the solutions obtained on the simulator are incorrect. Are there ways to make the answers correct?
The picture shows the cost function, where the first expression means the condition for the maximum filling of each backpack. The second condition means that each item can only be put in one backpack
[image]

```
from qiskit_optimization import QuadraticProgram
from qiskit_optimization.algorithms import MinimumEigenOptimizer
from qiskit.utils import algorithm_globals
from qiskit.algorithms.minimum_eigensolvers import SamplingVQE
from qiskit.algorithms.optimizers import SPSA
from qiskit.circuit.library import RealAmplitudes
from qiskit.primitives import Sampler
from qiskit.algorithms import VQE
from qiskit.algorithms.optimizers import COBYLA
from qiskit import IBMQ
class QuantumOptimizer_knpack:
    def __init__(self, cost, pack):

        self.cost = cost  #cost of items
        self.pack = pack  #capacity of backpacks
        self.n = len(cost)
        self.m = len(pack)

    #create cost function
    def binary_representation(self, x_sol=0):

        cost = np.array([self.cost])
        pack = self.pack
        n = self.n
        m = self.m

        # Some variables I will use
        a = 1   
        b = 1  
        Id_n = np.eye(m)
        for i in range(len(pack)):
            Id_n[i][i] = (1 / (pack[i] * a)) ** 2
        Im_n_1 = np.matmul(np.transpose(cost), cost)
        Iv_n_1 = np.array([1 / (i * a) for i in pack])
        Iv_n = cost[0]

        I_on = np.eye(n)
        Im_on = np.ones([m, m])
        I_on_1 = np.ones(n)
        Im_on_1 = np.ones(m)

        Q = np.kron(Id_n, Im_n_1) + b * np.kron(I_on, Im_on)
        g = (

            - 2 * np.kron(Iv_n_1, Iv_n)
            - 2 * b * np.kron(I_on_1, Im_on_1)

        )
        c = (1 + b) * m

        try:
            max(x_sol)
            fun = (
            lambda x: np.dot(np.around(x), np.dot(Q, np.around(x)))
                      + np.dot(g, np.around(x))
                      + c
            )
            cost = fun(x_sol)
        except:
            cost = 0

        return Q, g, c, cost

    def construct_problem(self, Q, g, c) -> QuadraticProgram:
        qp = QuadraticProgram()
        for i in range(self.n * self.m):
            qp.binary_var(str(i))
        qp.objective.quadratic = Q
        qp.objective.linear = g
        qp.objective.constant = c
        return qp

    def solve_problem(self, qp):
        algorithm_globals.random_seed = 10598
        vqe = SamplingVQE(sampler=Sampler(), optimizer=SPSA(), ansatz=RealAmplitudes())
        optimizer = MinimumEigenOptimizer(min_eigen_solver=vqe)
        result = optimizer.solve(qp)
        _, _, _, level = self.binary_representation(x_sol=result.x)
        return result.x, level

    def solve_problem_to_server(self, qp):
        global a
        global conect_flag
        if conect_flag == False:
            conect()
        op, offset = qp.to_ising()
        provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub='ibm-q')
        backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_qasm_simulator')
        optimizer = COBYLA(maxiter=200)
        ansatz = RealAmplitudes()
        vqe = VQE(ansatz=ansatz, optimizer=optimizer, quantum_instance=backend)
        result = vqe.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(operator=op)
   

        return result 
 def conect():
     token = "IBMQ_token"
     IBMQ.save_account(token)
     IBMQ.load_account()
#example task
points_cost = [10,7,4,4,3]
pack = [25, 3]
quantum_optimizer = QuantumOptimizer_knpack(points_cost, pack)
Q, g, c, binary_cost = quantum_optimizer.binary_representation()
qp = quantum_optimizer.construct_problem(Q, g, c)
result = quantum_optimizer.solve_problem_to_server(qp)
'''
the result must contain the string "1111000001" which means that the first four items are put 
in the first backpack, and the last one in the second
'''
```